# Show that $V$ is an abstract affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let $\rho : (X, Y) \rightarrow (-X, -Y)$ be the action of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} = \{ -1, 1 \}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2} = \mathbb{A}^{2}(\mathbb{C})$ and $V = \mathbb{A}^{2}_{\mathbb{C}} / \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Define $\mathbb{C}[V]$ as $\mathbb{C}[X, Y]^{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}$ to be the algebra of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}-$invariant polynomials $p(-X, -Y) = p(X, Y)$. Show that $V$ is an abstract affine variety.

I am completely lost on this one. We are only given the definition of an abstract affine variety:

Definition. An abstract affine variety $V$ is a set $V$ together with a finitely generated $k$-algebra $k[V]$ of maps $f : V \rightarrow K$, which map the $k$-rational points of $V$ to $k$, such that for some choice of generators $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}$ the map $V \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n}(K)$, $P \mapsto (x_{1}(P), \ldots, x_{n}(P))$ gives a bijection between $V$ and an affine variety im$(V) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n}(K)$.

Edit: The polynomials that are invariant under the action are $X^{2}, XY,$ and $Y^{2}$. Pick as generators $x_{1} = X^{2}$, $x_{2} = XY$, and $x_{3} = Y^{2}$.

Comment: Well, you'd better start by finding the algebra of invariants, right? That is, can you compute what $\Bbb C[X,Y]^{\Bbb Z_2}$ is?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The issue is that I do not know what an algebra of invariants is. Our course material did not cover that. We were only introduced to the definition of an abstract algebraic variety.

Comment: If you could only use things that were in your course, you wouldn't be here, now would you? If you don't know what the algebra of invariants is, you could do some searching on your own (there are many fine search engines on the web), and if that's not sufficient, you could explain the parts you don't understand this in your post. The algebra of invariants is the polynomials which don't change under the action of $\Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: Thanks again. I will work on it today and tomorrow and get back if I am stuck somewhere.

Comment: I think that the polynomials which do not change under the action are $X^{2}, XY$, and $Y^{2}$. We then have $\mathbb{C}[V] = \mathbb{C}[X, Y]^{\mathbb{Z}_{2}} \cong \mathbb{C}[X^{2}, XY, Y^{2}]$. Is this correct? What comes next?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You should add this progress to your post via an [edit]. What's next is that you need to verify the definition you've written down: pick generators and show that the map described in your definition is a bijection.

Comment: What relations do your generators $x_1, x_2, x_3$ satisfy?